# GStreamer won't show video

Tags: video, gstreamer, 19.10, vaapi

I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad P1. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 but had problems with stability and supporting an external monitor so I upgraded to 19.04. This seems to work well but now I'm trying to use GStreamer and it won't display video. Even the basic test:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

won't work.

My colleague suggested removing gstreamer1.0-vaapi:

```
sudo apt-get remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

This has fixed the problem of no video - the test above now works. Is there any way of getting the HW support to work?

I've raised https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer-vaapi/+bug/1849735 for this.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer-vaapi/+bug/1826201 Bugreport, maybe helpful.

Comment: I don't think it's the same problem - I don't get any video at all.